# Greek in Beamer

Tags: beamer, greek

How do I get to write Greek in Beamer /without/ using Latin transliterations?
The following did not work.

```
\documentclass[lualatex]{beamer}
\usepackage[polutonikogreek,british]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{ebgaramond}

\begin{document}
\title{Not a presentation}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Hullo}
  Hullo, world.
  \textgreek{aisqron}
  \textgreek{καλόν}
  καλόν
\end{frame}
\end{document}

%%% Local Variables:
%%% mode: latex
%%% TeX-master: t
%%% TeX-engine: luatex
%%% End:
```

`aisqron` shows, `καλόν` does not.
I don't know that I need Luatex, but my attempt with standard Latex failed too.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried choosing a font that definitively supports greek?

Comment: @TeXnician, yes, but `\setmainfont` didn't work.

Comment: What do you mean with setmainfont didn't work? What was the error? And maybe you should define a `\greekfont`.

Comment: This has nothing to do with `beamer`. In any class, you need to specify a font that supports Greek.

Comment: The first `\textgreek` works, so the default has Greek letters.  For some reason they are only accessible through transliteration.  There was no error: it just didn't change the displayed font.

Comment: A first step is selecting the serif font theme for beamer. Setting the serif font won’t change anything otherwise.

Comment: Note also that there’s a difference between fonts which have some Greek letters for use as symbols and fonts which support polytonic Greek.  EB Garamond is a good choice for polytonic Greek.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

beamer uses a sans serif font, so you must set this font to a font that knows greek:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[polutonikogreek,british]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setsansfont{ebgaramond}
\begin{document}
\title{Not a presentation}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Hullo}
  Hullo, world.
  \textgreek{aisqron} καλόν 
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perhaps it's better to use `\usefonttheme{serif}` and `\setmainfont`.

Comment: As ebgaramond is a serif font probably yes. But I didn't know if this will be really your final font and the main point is that you should set the fontfamily actually used.