# Problem with lowercase Greek fonts in beamer

Tags: beamer, greek

I am writing  a beamer presentation language being  Greek. The uppercase Greek fonts appear, the lowercase do not. I am working in xelatex.

```
\documentclass[xelatex]{beamer} 
\usepackage{xgreek} 
\usepackage[polutonikogreek,british]{babel} \usetheme{Warsaw} 
\title{ΜΙΚΡΗ ἱστορία ἑνός ἱστορικοῦ πανεπιστημίου} \subtitle[Short Title]{ΔΙΑΣΗΜΟΙ ἐρευνητές} \author{Dr. Σπυρίδων Καναβός} \institute{Iamblichus} \
date 
\begin{document} 
\begin{frame} 
\titlepage 
\end{frame} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: As always on this site, you are much much more likely to get any help if you provide a full but minimal example that others can just copy and test as is.

Comment: My code is: \documentclass[xelatex]{beamer}

\usepackage{xgreek}
\usepackage[polutonikogreek,british]{babel}

\usetheme{Warsaw}

\title{ΜΙΚΡΗ ἱστορία ἑνός ἱστορικοῦ πανεπιστημίου}
\subtitle[Short Title]{ΔΙΑΣΗΜΟΙ ἐρευνητές}
\author{Dr. Σπυρίδων Καναβός}
\institute{Iamblichus}
\date

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\end{document}

Comment: note that comments are not for large amounts of text, update your question instead. Seems Bernard did that for you.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/397404/greek-in-beamer "beamer uses a sans serif font, so you must set this font to a font that knows greek"

Answer (score 3):

You can configure Babel to automatically detect Greek or Latin script, and change the language (including font and hyphenation patterns) for you without any extra `\selectlanguage` or `\foreignlanguage` commands.  In XeTeX:

```
\documentclass[xelatex]{beamer} 
%\usepackage{xgreek} 
\usepackage[polutonikogreek,british]{babel}
\usepackage[GreekAndCoptic,GreekExtended]{ucharclasses} % For auto-detecting language.

\setDefaultTransitions{\selectlanguage{british}}{\selectlanguage{british}}
\setTransitionTo{GreekAndCoptic}{\selectlanguage{polutonikogreek}}
\setTransitionTo{GreekExtended}{\selectlanguage{polutonikogreek}}

% Load a font family that supports polytonic Greek:
\babelfont{rm}{NewComputerModern10}
\babelfont{sf}{NewComputerModernSans10}
\babelfont{tt}{NewComputerModernMono10}

\usetheme{Warsaw} 
\title{ΜΙΚΡΗ ἱστορία ἑνός ἱστορικοῦ πανεπιστημίου}
\subtitle[Short Title]{ΔΙΑΣΗΜΟΙ ἐρευνητές}
\author{Dr. Σπυρίδων Καναβός}
\institute{Iamblichus}

\begin{document} 
\begin{frame} 
\titlepage 
\end{frame} 
\end{document}
```

For other engines, see [the MWEs here.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/601434/61644)

### PS

In the comments, you say the font command I used doesn’t work.  I actually didn’t use the exactly right one myself, and it won’t correctly switch to New Computer Modern 08 for footnote size.

There’s a bug in the `NewComputerModern.fontspec` file, or possibly in `fontspec`, such that `fontspec` cannot find a default file outside of a `SizeFeatures=` block to load.  For the moment, here’s an easy workaround (that might not work for you if the original didn’t) and a more robust one.

The easy workaround is to change to

```
\babelfont{rm}{CMU Serif}
\babelfont{sf}{CMU Sans Serif}
\babelfont{tt}{CMU Typewriter Text}
```

Or any other font of your choice, such as Libertinus Serif/Sans/Mono.

If XeTeX cannot find these names (or `NewComputerModernSans10`), your fonts are not properly indexed in the `fc-cache` database.  The correct solution to that will vary by your OS and TeX distribution.  With a custom TeX Live installation on Debian or Ubuntu Linux, for example, the command is something like: `sudo ln -s $(kpsewhich texlive-fontconfig.conf) /etc/fonts/conf.d/09-texlive.conf`, then re-run `fc-cache -f -s -v`.

The more robust solution is to find the configuration with `kpsewhich NewComputerModern.fontspec`, etc., copy the contents into your preamble, and make the necessary fixes yourself.  Here, that is:

```
\documentclass[xelatex]{beamer} 
%\usepackage{xgreek} 
\usepackage[polutonikogreek,british]{babel}
\usepackage[GreekAndCoptic,GreekExtended]{ucharclasses} % For auto-detecting language.

\setDefaultTransitions{\selectlanguage{british}}{\selectlanguage{british}}
\setTransitionTo{GreekAndCoptic}{\selectlanguage{polutonikogreek}}
\setTransitionTo{GreekExtended}{\selectlanguage{polutonikogreek}}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\defaultfontfeatures[NewComputerModernSans]
   {
    Extension      = .otf ,
    UprightFont=NewCMSans10-Regular,
    SizeFeatures={%
                  {Size= -8, UprightFont=NewCMSans08-Regular,%
                             ItalicFont=NewCMSans08-Oblique,%
                             BoldFont=NewCMSans10-Bold,%
                             BoldItalicFont=NewCMSans10-BoldOblique,%
                             SmallCapsFeatures={Numbers=OldStyle}},
                   {Size= 8, UprightFont=NewCMSans08-Regular,%
                             ItalicFont=NewCMSans08-Oblique,%
                             BoldFont=NewCMSans10-Bold,%
                             BoldItalicFont=NewCMSans10-BoldOblique,%
                             SmallCapsFeatures={Numbers=OldStyle}},
                  {Size= 9-, UprightFont=NewCMSans10-Regular,%
                             ItalicFont=NewCMSans10-Oblique,%
                             BoldFont=NewCMSans10-Bold,%
                             BoldItalicFont=NewCMSans10-BoldOblique,%
                             SmallCapsFeatures={Numbers=OldStyle}}
                             }}

% Load a font family that supports polytonic Greek:
%\babelfont{rm}{NewComputerModern}
\babelfont{sf}{NewComputerModernSans}
%\babelfont{tt}{NewComputerModernMono}

\usetheme{Warsaw} 
\title{ΜΙΚΡΗ ἱστορία ἑνός ἱστορικοῦ πανεπιστημίου}
\subtitle[Short Title]{ΔΙΑΣΗΜΟΙ ἐρευνητές}
\author{Dr. Σπυρίδων Καναβός}
\institute{Iamblichus}

\begin{document} 
\begin{frame} 
\titlepage 
\end{frame} 
\end{document}
```

The bug workaround is the first `UprightFont=` line under `\defaultfontfeatures`.

Comment: There is a problem. The three commands, \babelfont ~  used to load a font family for supporting polytonic Greek, are not accepted. I'm looking at it. In any case, thank you so much.

Comment: @SpyridonKanavos Although this was kind of extraneous to the original question, I edited in a few solutions.

Comment: The solution using the commands:
\babelfont{rm}[Language=Default]{DejaVu Serif}
\babelfont{sf}[Language=Default]{DejaVu Serif}
\babelfont{tt}[Language=Default]{DejaVu Sans Mono}
works perfectly.
I’m not dealing with the last solution you have suggested, because it’s a bit complex, and I would keep it simple at this stage. In any case, thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

[image: example]

Firstly, as per the related question, since beamer uses sans font, tell `babel` which font to use for sans (`sf`) when doing `polutonikogreek` (`\babelfont` command, needs `fontspec` package); and secondly, for xelatex, tell `babel` what language with `\selectlanguage{polutonikogreek}` (lualatex can automatically detect the script and switch fonts).

In the example, I set the font to Noto Sans, but `sf` family could also have been set to Noto Serif (or other font), if you find that is legible and suitable.

MWE

```
\documentclass[xelatex]{beamer} 
\usetheme{Warsaw} 
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[polutonikogreek,british]{babel} 
\babelfont[polutonikogreek]{sf}{Noto Sams}
\usepackage{xgreek} 
\title{ΜΙΚΡΗ ἱστορία ἑνός ἱστορικοῦ πανεπιστημίου} 
\subtitle[Short Title]{ΔΙΑΣΗΜΟΙ ἐρευνητές} 
\author{Dr. Σπυρίδων Καναβός} \institute{Iamblichus} 
\begin{document} 
\selectlanguage{polutonikogreek}
\begin{frame} 
\titlepage 
\end{frame} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.
Obviously, you mean “Noto Sans”
There are two warnings : Font  “Noto Sans” does not contain script" Default " and: The current font is not a standard family (babel). Note that I use Texlive 2019 in Debian 10 GNU/Linux. Any way, it works perfect and thank you so much.

Comment: Try Noto Serif as the sans font (like putting sugar in the salt jar: any font can be assigned to any family) and see. Babel/fontspec warnings are informational; not all font designers set up all scripts and languages in all fonts, so Default acts as the fallback, more or less.